# Nonlinear system stability analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

How to find an appropriate Lyapunov function to show the stability of a system:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -(x-1)(x-2)^2$

around its equilibrium point $x = 1$?

By linearizing this system, it can be shown that the $x=1$ point is locally asymptotically stable.

What is the appropriate Lyapunov function?

Answer (score 1):

$V(x)=(x-1)^2$ is a (strict) Lyapunov function.

**Added:** Indeed, $V\ge0$ and $V(x)=0$ if and only if $x=1$. Moreover,
$$
\dot V(x)=-2(x-1)^2(x-2)^2
$$
and so for $x\in(0,2)\setminus\{1\}$ we have $\dot V(x)<0$. Hence, $V$ is a strict Lyapunov function, which shows that the equilibrium point $x=1$ is asymptotically stable.

Comment: I think that V(x) can show Xe = 1 is stable, but not asymptotically stable.

Comment: I don't think you could find a class K function f(x) satisfying dV/dt <= -f(x)

Comment: Since you don't seem to be convinced, I added some details.